# Formatting decimal as percent showing 100% for 0,98

Tags: vba, format

I'm showing a progress bar in %.

When it almost reaches the final goal (like 0,98 or 0,99) it is showing 100%.

Here is the code.

```
main.Shapes("shape1").DrawingObject.Text = Format(result, "(0%)")
```

Where `result` goes down from 0,00 to 1,00.

Is there a trick to not show 100% if `result` is not 100% yet?

Comment: What type of shape is `shape1`?

Comment: Well, i created at Insert>Forms>TextBox and never set a type for him at the code.

Comment: Can't reproduce this behavior - maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: What is `main`?

Comment: Which *application* is this? That could certainly affect the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give it as many decimal places as it needs not to round the number.

```vb
result = 0.99999
fmtPattern = "0%"
If result >= 0 And result < 1 Then
    decPlaces = Len(CStr(result)) - 4
    If decPlaces > 0 Then
        fmtPattern = "0." & String(decPlaces, "0") & "%"
    End If
End If
main.Shapes("shape1").DrawingObject.Text = Format(result, "(" & fmtPattern & ")")
```